# Perfect Secrecy other than One-time Pad

Tags: one-time-pad, perfect-secrecy

The most known example cipher reaching perfect secrecy is One-time Pad, which employs modulus addition for encryption and decryption.

Is there any other **well-known** cipher **no less practical** than OTP that reachs perfect secrecy?

- Note: Practical application is necessary. For extempore constructions, See answers here
  [What operations provide perfect secrecy other than modulo addition](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/75734/what-operations-provide-perfect-secrecy-other-than-modulo-addition)
- Shamir's secret sharing applys to multiple parties, which is a different application scenario.
- Answers here are believed to be homogenous with OTP.
  [How many perfect secrecy systems are there?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/80687/how-many-perfect-secrecy-systems-are-there)

Comment: Hiya :-)  Technically, modular maths isn't a requirement. The transformation has only to be bijective, which is how OTPs [were](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-0RfS23DWogo/Wd91r2u1m-I/AAAAAAAACVo/1SnPwcx1VfkJiZvFHE1qp2Wap1wa3t_TQCLcBGAs/s1600/diana1.jpg) implemented decades ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a famous result about perfect secrecy, usually called Shannon's theorem:

> If an encryption scheme has perfect secrecy, then $|\mathcal{K}| \ge |\mathcal{M}|$, where $\mathcal{K}$ is the set of possible keys and $\mathcal{M}$ is the set of possible plaintexts.

One-time pad achieves equality $|\mathcal{K}| = |\mathcal{M}|$, which is the fewest number of keys possible according to Shannon's theorem.
If you seek a scheme that is "no less practical" than OTP, then I suppose that you too require $|\mathcal{K}| = |\mathcal{M}|$.

OTP also has a deterministic encryption algorithm, so any scheme that is "no less practical" should also have deterministic encryption.
(Also, randomized encryption would needlessly increase the ciphertext size.)

With a deterministic encryption scheme, we can imagine writing out the entire truth table of $\textsf{Enc}(K,M)$, with rows indexed by $K \in \mathcal K$ and columns indexed by $M = \mathcal M$.
As $|\mathcal M|=|\mathcal K|$, the table is a square.
For decryption to be possible, every row must have distinct entries -- this corresponds to the property that $\textsf{Enc}(K,\cdot)$ is a bijection for every $K$.
Every column must also have distinct entries: if the column corresponding to $M$ does not have distinct entries, then it is missing some $C$, meaning that no key encrypts $M$ to $C$.
But then observing the ciphertext $C$ means the plaintext could not have been $M$, and this violates perfect secrecy.
(We know $C$ appears *somewhere* in the table as encryption of *some* plaintext, otherwise the condition on rows doesn't hold.)

The truth table of $\textsf{Enc}$ is therefore a [Latin square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square), making it the truth table of a [quasigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup) operation.
Let's call the quasigroup $(\mathcal G, \boxplus)$.
Then $\mathcal M$ and $\mathcal K$ are both isomorphic to $\mathcal G$ and the encryption algorithm is $\textsf{Enc}(K,M) = K \boxplus M$.

So the question of alternative perfectly secret encryption schemes reduces to the question of identifying a suitable quasigroup.

Answer (score 1):

There's computational perfect secrecy and information-theoretic perfect secrecy, and OTP belongs to the latter.

If it's **well-known** *information-theoretic* perfect secrecy that you seek and is **no less practical**, then none.